# Changing custom tableview cell button background image using NSNotification from non-tableview host class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, fppopover

1) I have a simple table view hosted by view controller and cell hosted by custom `UITableViewCell` class. A button on my cell drops down a menu (a simple table view controller loading from the non-host 'out of the picture' class using `FPPopoverMenu`).

2) The problem is I want to update my button background image on dropdown menu row selection which involves my 'out of the picture dropdown menu tableview class' and my 'custom table view cell class' totally deserting the host of my custom `UITableViewCell`.

3) I tried using `NSNotification` like, I successfully did for a simple scenario involving only host-class and dropdown menu class but now its the custom tableview cell (which is a repeating entity) and dropdown class I want to communicate.. Please help. I set up `NSNotification` but background image stays the same, means notification doesn't reach/doesn't reach in time.

4) Apparently I need 10 reputation to post image (:-[) so here's the link:

[image]

As shown by the image, I have fired notification on dropdown's didSelectRow, when Hide is pressed, background should change otherwise, if show is pressed it should be green as shown..as i did before but this doesn't do anything for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post some code on how you update the button background right now? I mean, how you access the cell ?

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(ChangeButtonBackgr:) name:@"changePic" object:nil];

Comment: simply in awake view from nib i registered for notification

Comment: and after requisite setup i posted notification from didSelectRowAtIndex of my popover menu tableView class

Comment: What you are doing inside `ChangeButtonBackgr` ? And is it getting called ? And yes, don't add code in comment. Please edit your question and post code there only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use blocks.

You need to add

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^didSelectAction)(NSIndexPath *indexPath);
```

to view controller which is shown in popover.

than in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` call this block

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.didSelectAction)
        self.didSelectAction(indexPath);
}
```

So when you create a popover you should provide additional handler.
Something like this

Add new action to your button

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    [[cell button] addTarget:self action:@selector(showPopoverFromButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void) showPopoverFromButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    //Your table view which is shown in popover
    UITableViewController *controller = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setDidSelectAction:^{
         [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }];
    FPPopoverMenu *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];        
    [popover show];
}
```

Comment: looks like a solution i'll check!!

Comment: the thing is, read point 2) of the question.. i think the only way is protocols and delegates... bcoz the host of cell is not being involved here

Comment: I have updated answer. As I understand you handle button action in your cell class? And in my approach the viewController is handler.

Comment: exactly!! so is this approach fine to try now?

Comment: please confirm what u meant by : You need to add @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^didSelectAction)(NSIndexPath *indexPath); property to popover table view.  popover table view is the actual FPPopoverController or the table view that loads as FPPopover?(the one showing below button in image)

Comment: FPPopoverController doesn't have a table view :) So i meant the one showing below button in image. And again I will update my answer to clarify everything

Comment: i gave each cell the selector and tag in cellForRowAtIndex and used the tag to update specifically the button background in cell which's button was tapped using a check against indexPath.row and sender.tag. worked perfectly!